# Java's Math.Pow() function returning confusing results

Tags: java, pow

I am working with the Math.pow() function, and have the following code:

```
double monthlyRate = (0.7d / 12);
int loanLength = 3;

double powerTest = Math.pow(1.00583, 36);
double powerResult = Math.pow((1 + monthlyRate),(loanLength * 12));
```

When this is run through the debugger, the values become

```
powerTest => 1.2327785029794363
powerResult => 7.698552870922063
```

The first is the correct one.  I've stepped into the Math.pow function on both of the assignment lines. For powerTest,
the parameters for Math.pow are
    double a => 1.00583
    double b => 36.0

For powerResult, they are
    double a => 1.0058333333333333
    double b => 36.0

I know that this is an issue with the way floating point math is performed by the machine, I'm just not sure how to correct it. I tried doing the following before the calculation with poor results:

```
monthlyRate = Math.round(monthlyRate * 1000) / 1000;
```

Comment: What do you expect from (1+(0.7/12))^(3⋅12)? I get  7.6985528709220588862786 in a regular calculator.

Comment: On Java you should use BigDecimal to perform money operations. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`1 + monthlyRate` is `1.0583...`, not `1.00583`.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression 0.7d/12 = 0.0583, in the powerTest expression you are using 0.00583.

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the problem is that `0.7/12 ~ 0.058333`, and `1.0583 > 1.00583`.  My bet is this is the true source of your discrepancy, the floating point adjustments have little to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously a such big difference in the resut(1.23... and 7.70) is not related to the way floats are coded but more than you made a mistake somewhere
1+0.7/12 = 1.0583 is different from 1.00583 ;-).

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.round(monthlyRate * 1000) / 1000.0;
```

You were using integer division.

Comment: Ignore this, the actual problem is extra zero, as **axtavt** noted. I leave the answer, in case OP actually wanted to perform rounding.

Comment: Thanks Nikita, I'll note that if I have to write a similar function in the future

Answer (score 1):

On Java you can use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to perform money operations resulting on accurate numbers: it is the [Sun/Oracle recommended way](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal) to store money numbers.

```
// I'm using Strings for most accuracy

BigDecimal monthlyRate = new BigDecimal("0.7").divide(new BigDecimal(12));
int loanLength = 3;

BigDecimal powerTest = new BigDecimal("1.00583").pow(36);
BigDecimal powerResult = BigDecimal.ONE.add(monthlyRate).pow(loanLength * 12);
```

Comment: Please, explain your downvotes. The OP is performing money operations, he *should be* using BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
monthlyRate = ((double)Math.round(monthlyRate * 1000)) / 1000;
```